# How to route traffic from 2 different VMs through 2 different vpn connections on linux host?

Tags: vpn, linux-mint

I am trying to contain my VMs to OpnVPN traffic only. I have 2 different VMs I am hosting on Linux Mint. I would like to establish the VPN connections on the host, but not have the host use them for its connection. (Possibly even have the host use another VPN connection sometimes.) I would like each of the VMs to use the established VPN connections. I am using virtualbox and KVM. I'm not sure where begin. Any ideas on how to set this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what kind of VPN client are you using? do the connections manifest as virtual network interfaces that are visible to IP routing rules? In vbox you can set up a custom virtual network and define the host interface, but you may be limited to physical interfaces. no idea with KVM.

Comment: most of the time this involves policy (source based) routing on the host. Consider the host a router and VMs other systems behind the router. here's an [OpenVPN example](https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/openvpn-source-based-routing/). it's a bit outdated (eg there's not anymore a ipv4 route cache) The principle is the same for different vpns (or a multihomed router)

Comment: Frank, I would be using openvpn. Going off of your comment I found this..https://serverfault.com/questions/234154/how-to-route-traffic-from-a-virtualbox-vm-only-over-a-vpn . That adds some clarity. I guess I'm still trying to visualize the best approach. I will read through these links. I just wanted to make sure I shouldn't use something like "network namespace" or something. Thank you! A.B. thank you for the link I will read through now. Thank you!